# How to use "++" operation to increase pointer of a char array in a structure in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm studying pointer in C and I have a question about how to use ++ operator in a char array in a structure.

Here is my structure:

```
typedef struct{
    char firstname[32];
    char lastname[32];
} person;
```

Also, here is my function which compare two people's name:

```
int compare_firstname(const person* first, const person* second)
{
    while(first->firstname != '\0' || second->firstname != '\0')
    {
        /**
            Do something awesome!
        */
        ++first->firstname; // here is my problem
        ++second->firstname;// here is my problem
    }
}
```

I want to access elements of these two char array without "[]" to understand pointer well. Do I make `const char*` local variable? If so, can you explain the reason?

Thank you!

Comment: These are arrays, you can't increment them.

Comment: Uh, arrays are not pointers.

Comment: "...to increase pointer of a char array"? Where did you get the idea that there's a "pointer" there that you can "increase"?

Comment: @ForceBru oh thank you.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh my god. I got what I misunderstand!

Comment: @AnT Yeah, I just understand what I misunderstand.

Comment: Good C book is required. Nor YT or "codes from internet"

Comment: @PeterJ Can you recommend any good C books for me?

Comment: Kernighan and Ritchie - C programming language - pointers are very well explained there. Probably most of the C programmers were learning from it

Comment: @PeterJ Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Books are much better than any other sources.

Comment: @PeterJ Yes! I bought the book what you recommended :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many other people here have provided answers involving using an extra `char*` pointer to get this to work. To elaborate a bit on why that is, remember that in C arrays and pointers - while related to one another - are not the same thing.

A pointer is kind of like a cursor - it says "go over here." If you point a pointer into an array, you can use `++` and `--` to advance forward and backward in the array. The pointer itself isn't the array - it's just a way of keeping track of where you are in the array.

An array variable represents a series of values. Think of it as a block of objects - the idea of "incrementing" a block of objects isn't well-defined in the same way that incrementing a pointer is. You can't apply `++` or `--` to arrays for this reason.

If you want to step through the elements of an array one at a time, you can do so by getting a pointer to the start of the array, then advancing that pointer forward and backward over the array. That way, the array - the actual elements themselves - stays unmodified, but the position in the array - the pointer - changes. That's why it's legal to do something like

```
const char* cursor = first->firstName; // Look at the first element.
cursor++; // Now you're looking at the second element!
```

but not

```
first->firstName++; // Oops - can't increment an array
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are not pointers you created. They are arrays. To create a pointer that is equivalent to an array in function, you should do the following:

```
//For heap allocation
char *point = malloc(sizeof(char)*32));

//For stack allocation
char ary[32];
char *point = &ary;
```

From there, incrementing pointer will move it along a memory address at a time. When comparing the characters though, as you do here:

```
first->firstname != '\0'
```

Make sure you de-reference. Without doing so you are comparing the memory address to the character code of '\0'.

So, the line would essentially be:

```
*first->firstname != '\0'
```

Make sure you create a new pointer that points to the first memory address of each string, though. You don't want to modify the one inside the data structure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand what I don't understand!!

Comment: Firstly, just because you use an explicit pointer does not mean that "you must allocate the memory on the heap". "Heap" has nothing to do with this topic. Secondly, the question is tagged [C]. What is `new char[32]` doing here?

Comment: Sure, but in this case how would you allocate the memory without doing it on the heap? Minus creating the array as they did above and pointing to the first memory address?

Comment: Yes, you got it! For example, by "creating the array as they did above and pointing to the first memory address"! Pointers are not in any way tied to heap. The purpose of heap is manual control of lifetime/storage duration. If you don't need manual control of lifetime, you don't need heap. This question is not about controlling lifetime at all.

Comment: @AnT whoopsie. Good catch, I've been using too much C++ lately, apparently :p

Comment: Oh "new" is not for C. Thank you guys. I learn a lot from this answer.

Comment: @MMX right, new is not a keyword in C. Calling new in C++ is equivalent to calling malloc, it just automatically determines the size of what you are allocating.

Answer (score 1):

Array designators are non-modifiable lvalues. You may not apply the operator ++ to an array name.

You can use standard C function `strcmp` instead of character to character comparison in a loop.

If you want to use a loop inside your function then it can look the following way

```
int compare_firstname(const person* first, const person* second)
{
    const char *lhs = first->firstname;
    const char *rhs = second->firstname;

    while ( *lhs != '\0' && *lhs == *rhs )
    {
        ++lhs;
        ++rhs;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to access those arrays through pointers, you'll have to create some
local ones:

```
int compare_firstname(const person* first, const person* second)
{
    char *f = first->firstname;
    char *s = second->firstname;

    while(*f != '\0' || *s != '\0')
    {
        // Do something here.
        ++f;
        ++s;
    }
}
```